# Creating trail over an already made canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

So I am trying to implement a concept of shooting star over an already drawn canvas of slowly moving stars. But I haven't found a way to do so. I tried implementing an array to make it look so but the trail isn't as efficient.

This code is as follows:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


var mouse = {
    x : innerWidth/2,
    y : innerHeight/2
};

var colors = [
    '#3399CC',
    '#67B8DE',
    '#91C9E8',
    '#B4DCED',
    '#E8F8FF'
];



addEventListener('resize', function () {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;

    init();
});

var isClicked = false;
addEventListener('click', function () {
    mouse.x = event.clientX;
    mouse.y = event.clientY;
    isClicked = true;
});



function randomIntFromRange (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function randomColor (colors) {
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}



function Stars (x, y, radius, dy, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.color = color;

    this.draw = function () {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        c.shadowColor = this.color;
        c.shadowBlur = 15;
        c.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        c.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
    }

    this.update = function () {
        if (this.y < -10) {
            this.y = canvas.height + 10;
            this.x = randomIntFromRange(this.radius, canvas.width);
        }
        this.y -= this.dy;

        this.draw();
    }
}

function ShootingStar (x, y, radius) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;

    this.draw = function () {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        c.shadowColor = "red";
        c.shadowBlur = 15;
        c.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        c.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        c.fillStyle = "red";
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
    }

    this.update = function () {
        this.x += 10;
        this.y += 10;

        this.draw();
    }
}



let stars = [];
let shooting_star = [];

function init () {
    stars = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        var stars_radius = randomIntFromRange(2, 3);
        var stars_x = randomIntFromRange(stars_radius, canvas.width);
        var stars_y = randomIntFromRange(stars_radius, canvas.height);
        var stars_dy = Math.random() / 6;
        var color = randomColor(colors);
        stars.push(new Stars(stars_x, stars_y, stars_radius, stars_dy, color));
    }
}

function Explode () {
    shooting_star = [];
    var shooting_star_radius = 3;
    var shooting_star_x = mouse.x;
    var shooting_star_y = mouse.y;
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        shooting_star.push(new ShootingStar(shooting_star_x, shooting_star_y, shooting_star_radius));
        if (shooting_star_radius > 0.2) {
            shooting_star_radius -= .2;
        }
        var initiator = randomIntFromRange(-1, 1);
        console.log(initiator);
        shooting_star_x -= 3;
        shooting_star_y -= 3;
    }
}

function animate () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) 
        stars[i].update();
    for (var i = 0; i < shooting_star.length; i++) 
        shooting_star[i].update();

    if (isClicked == true) {
        Explode();
        isClicked = false;
    }
}

init();
animate();
```

Here is the jsfiddle to it
https://jsfiddle.net/qjug4qdz/

I basically want the shooting star to come from a random location to the point where my mouse is clicked, but the trail is difficult to work with using an array.

Comment: Maybe get the coordinates of the clicked point and then get random coordinates from the edge of the canvas. Then do some simple vector calculations to get the trajectory for the shooting star. Just wondering.

Comment: Yes, that I am aware of, but the main concern here is to get the trail effect.

Comment: Can't you just draw the trail onto the vector?

Answer (score 0):

### Basic particles

For the particular effect you are looking for you can use a basic particle system.

As the shooting star moves you will drop a particle that starts with the star velocity and then slows and fades out.

#### The particle

You first start with the particle. I like to use `Object.assign` when creating objects but you can use any method you like, class, new, factory...

```
// This defines a particle and is copied to create new particles
const starDust = {
    x : 0,  // the current position
    y : 0, 
    dx : 0,  // delta x,y (velocity)
    dy : 0,
    drag : 0, // the rate that the particle slows down.
    life : 0, // count down till particle is removed
    age : 0, // the starting value of life
    draw(){ // function to update and draw the particle
        this.x += this.dx;   // move it
        this.y += this.dy;
        this.dx *= this.drag;  // slow it down
        this.dy *= this.drag;
        const unitLife = (this.life / this.age); // get the life left as a value 
                                                 // from 0 to 1 where 0 is end
        ctx.globalAlpha = unitLife;   // set the alpha
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,4,0,Math.PI); // draw the particle


        this.life -= 1; // count down
        return this.life > 0; // return true if still alive
     }
```

#### Be memory aware.

A common mistake when creating particle systems is that people forget that creating and destroying objects will add a lot of work to javascripts memory management. The worst of which is GC (Garbage Collection). GC is a major source of lag and if you are wasteful with memory it will impact the quality of the animation. For simple particles it may not be noticeable, but you may want hundreds of complex particles spawning each frame. This is when GC realy hurts the animation.

Most Game engines reduce the GC impact by reusing objects rather than dereferencing and recreating. A common method is an object pool, where a second array holds objects that are no longer used. When a new object is needed then the pool is first checked, if there is an unused object, it is used, else a new object is created.

This way you never delete any particles, greatly reducing the GC workload, and preventing your animation from dropping frames (if you use a lot of particles)

#### Particle needs initializer

But you need to provide a way to re-initialize the object. Thus add the function `init` to the particle that will set it up to be used again

```
    init(x,y,vx,vy){ // where x,y and velocity vx,vy of shooting star
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dx = vx;
        this.dy = vy;
        // give a random age
        this.age = (Math.random() * 100 + 60) | 0; // in frames and | 0 floors the value
        this.life = this.age; // and set the life countdown
        this.drag = Math.random() * 0.01 + 0.99; // the drag that slows the particle down
     }
}  // end of starDust object.
```

#### The arrays

To manage all the particles we create object that has arrays and methods for adding, creating and rendering the particles. In this case I will call it `dust`

```
const dust = {
     particles : [], // array of active particles
     pool : [], // array of unused particels
     createParticle(particleDesc){  // creates a new particle from particleDesc
         return Object.assign({},particleDesc);
     },
     add(x,y,vx,vy){ // where x,y and velocity vx,vy
         var dust; 
         if(this.pool.length){  // are there any particles in the pool
             dust = this.pool.pop(); // get one 
         }else{                 // else there are no spare particles so create a new one
             dust = this.createParticle(starDust);
         }
         dust.init(x,y,vx,vy); // init  the particle
         this.items.push(dust); // put it in the active particle array
         return dust;           // return it (sometimes you want to do something with it)
      },
      draw(){ // updates and draws all active particles
          var i = 0;
          while(i < this.items.length){ // iterate each particle in items
              if(this.items[i].draw() === false){ // is it dead??
                   this.pool.push(this.items.splice(i,1)[0]); // if dead put in the pool for later
              }else{ i ++ } // if not dead get index of next particle
          }
      }
   }//end of dust object
```

#### Using the particle system

The simplest way to create a particle is to use a random number and set the chance of a particle being created every frame.

In your main loop

```
 // assuming that the falling star is called star and has an x,y and dx,dy (delta)
 if(star) {   // only if there is a start to spawn from
    // add a particle once every 10 frame (on average
    if(Math.random() < 0.1) { 
          dust.add(star.x, star.y, star.dx, star.dy); // add some dust at the shooting starts position and speed
    }
 }

 dust.draw(); // draw all particles
```

And that is it.